# Verisign Signing Key into Debian?

Tags: debian, code-signing, x509certificate, gnupg

I have a (paid) code signing certificate from verisign/symnatic I use to sign my code in windows.

is it possible to use the same certificate to sign a debian package?  How do I get it into GPG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debian uses a different model of trust, which is based on a web-of-trust of Debian developers (gpg), instead of a commercial certificates (verisign,...).

so the answer is: *no*. you cannot simply use your verisign *certificate* to gpg-sign debian packages.

if you want to sign your debian packages, simply get yourself a gpg key, and use it to sign your packages.
to have your users *accept* your signiture, you have to options:

- the private way

  - set up your own repository

    e.g. following [How to setup a Debian Repository](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository)
  - sign the entire repository with your key

    `gpg -abs -o Release.gpg Release`
  - make your potential users install your key

    `gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 7F7A36F8`
    `gpg -a --export 7F7A36F8 | sudo apt-key add -`
  - and make them add your repository to their `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

as yuo can see, this is rather complicated, and requires the users to trust *you* beforehand (rather than trusting verisign). if you think your users cannot be bothered with this, there is still:

- the official way

  - [become a member of the Debian project](https://nm.debian.org/), and upload your packages directly to Debian